# TlSharp. При попытке получения сообщений канала выскакивает ошибка CHANNEL_INVALID

Tags: c#, telegram

Есть стандартный код:

```
TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLRequestGetHistory request = new TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLRequestGetHistory();
request.Peer = new TeleSharp.TL.TLInputPeerChannel { AccessHash = access_hash, ChannelId = channel_id };
request.MaxId = -1;
request.Limit = limit;
var message = await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLChannelMessages>(request);
```

Отлаживаюсь на нескольких телефонных номерах на одних и тех же каналах. На одном номере чтение происходит идеально, на других вылетает эксепшн CHANNEL_INVALID. Соответственно, возникает 2 вопроса: откуда лезет эта ошибка и что с этим делать? 
Жду ответа с нетерпением)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден. Телеграм на разных телефонных номерах может генерировать различный `access_hash` для одного и того же канала. Перед получением сообщений из канала, нужно по `id` и `title` канала получать новый `access_hash`